# Display dynamic title for dropdown listitem using razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have one dropdown in my MVC application.

I have a field in my model:

```
 public IList<SexGenderModel> SexualOrientationList { get; set; }
```

class for `SexGenderModel`:

```
public class SexGenderModel
    {
        public int? MasterID { get; set; }

        public string CodeDescription { get; set; }

        public string SNOMED { get; set; }

    }
```

In my view page I have used razor syntax

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SexualOrientationList, new SelectList(Model.SexualOrientationList, "MasterID", "CodeDescription"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control input-sm"})
```

Every list item has their own **SNOMED** which I want to display in tooltip.
Please note I want to display `tooltip` for `ListItem` not for selected item of dropdown.

How can I achieve this with razor?
Any other option to map attributes to `dropdownlist(Model.SexualOrientationList`) from backend? How?

Comment: You cant using razor (unless you want to write a dozen pages of code to create your own `HtmlHelper` extension methods). Would be far easier to use a javascript/jquery solution to add the `title` attribute

Comment: I want to display SNOMED as a tooltip. Can you please guide how can I do it using Jquery?

Comment: `var tooltips = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SexualOrientationList.Select(x => x.SNOMED)` gives you a javascript array containing the `SNOMED` values which you can then use to add the `title` attributes

Comment: but how can I map it to every list item? Because SNOMED is different for each item.

Comment: `var options = $(yourSelect).children('option'); for(var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) { options.eq(i).attr('title', tooltips[i]); }`. But your `DropDownListFor()` method will never work. You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects - you need a property to bind to (say `int SelectedGender`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanks for your response. Successfully added it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to add attribute "title" to each item in dropdown

```
<select>
        @foreach (var item in Model.SexualOrientationList)
        {
            <option title='@item.SNOMED' value="@item.MasterID">@item.CodeDescription</option>
        }
    </select>
```

Comment: I am restricted to use this. I have to use razor. Already ried. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Going further with @Khaled-Yosry 's answer:

@Ankita this DOES use Razor, so I'm not sure why you find yourself restricted.
If it's the `<select>` tag rendering you are worried about, you can append the necessary tags yourself:

All you need to add attribute "title" to each item in dropdown

```
<select name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.SexualOrientation)" id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.SexualOrientation)" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="">--Select one--</option>
    @foreach (var item in Model.SexualOrientationList)
    {
        <option title="@item.SNOMED" value="@item.MasterID" @(Model.SexualOrientation == item.MasterID ? "selected" : string.empty)>@item.CodeDescription</option>
    }
</select>
```

Also, don't forget to include a property in your Model which will actually be bound to the **selected** value of the dropdown list:

```
public int SexualOrientation { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can not use Select & Option directly.

Comment: Why not exactly? When using @Html helpers, all you are doing is generating html...

Comment: The `HtmlHelper`methods **do not** just generate html. They are responsible for correct 2-way model binding and this code will never do that.

Comment: Okay @StephenMuecke, correct, but you could mimic exactly that. Providing the name attribute through `@Html.NameFor()`, will bind the value correctly when posting. Only thing missing - I admit - is binding the selected value on page load. I updated my answer to reflect just that. This however is not an answer to the question why he "cannot use select & option directly"

Comment: That still does not do correct 2-way model binding (for example it does not take into account `ModelState`)

Comment: Oke, I did not know that. Could you perhaps provide some more info as to what's missing? I'm curious to know, to be honest.

Comment: @Nsevens, Study the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) :)